# Python3: Check if three sides provided able to form a triangle with nonzero area using triangle inequality

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, geometry

I am given a question: To determine if the three positive float values (a,b,c) given by a user can represent the three side-lengths of a triangle with nonzero area; by using the triangle inequality theorem. No error checking is needed on the user input.

The code below is the answer given on the answer sheet. However, I don't understand it, can someone kindly explain to me the purpose of 's' and 'eps' in the code? Thanks!

```
a = float (input ("Please enter a positive value, a: "))
b = float (input ("Please enter a positive value, b: "))
c = float (input ("Please enter a positive value, c: "))

s = (a + b - c) * (a + c - b) * (c + b - a)

eps = 0.0000001

if abs(s) > eps:
    print ("The 3 values form a triangle with non-zero area.")
else:
    print ("The 3 values DO NOT form a triangle at all.")
```

Comment: Is that really how the solution looks?  If so, it's wrong:  `abs(s) > eps` should be replaced with `s > eps`.

Comment: The answer is wrong. Even with the test “corrected” as [Mark Dickinson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson) suggests, it gives the wrong answer for a triangle with one vertex on Earth, one on the Moon, and one in the Andromeda galaxy (because `s` will be zero).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Agreed;  I didn't really want to get into that... :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a triangle, any two sides must add up to be greater than the third side.

If one of the sides was longer than the other two added up, then s would equal a negative number.  As long as the value of s is greater than eps (basically it's saying as long as s is greater than 0) then it turns out that the 3 points do form a valid triangle.

Does that help?  Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Oh okay, after your explanation I understand the 'if abs(s) > eps' part. I'm sorry but why use that equation for s? I don't get the equation. ):

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain s here:
a b and c represent the side lengths.  The 1st part of s is (a + b - c).  It's saying the length of side a + the length of side b - the length of side c.  In a valid triangle this has to be greater than 0 (by the triangle inequality theorem).  If it's not, then one will get a 0 or a negative value.

This is saying then that side c is longer than a and b combined. This means that in the 2nd part (a + c - b) we will get a positive answer. Same for the 3rd. But remember we must multiply all 3 parts together. Since we got a negative in part 1 our answer is negative.

Comment: @izaic3: You might want to explain why it's not possible that there are *two* negative factors and one positive factor in the formula for `s`.

Comment: No problem. Let's assume we have an invalid triangle. a = 1 b = 2 and c = 7.

In the first part we have (a + b - c).  This would = 1 + 2 - 7 = -4.  That's where our negative comes from.  Now in the following, we are adding c (which = 7) to a or b and then subtracting the remaining side.  In either case, there is no way we will get another negative number.  I'll finish my example.  In the second part we would have 1 + 7 - 2 = 6.  In the third we have 7 + 2 - 1 = 8.  So s = -4 * 6 * 8 = -192.  Therefor since s < eps, it's not a valid triangle.

Answer (score 0):

that there can't be two negative factors in s is obvious, as the sum of the smaller sides being smaller than the longest side implies that when the longest side is included in the sum, the sum will exceed either of the smaller sides